# Can I have a .bashrc when moving to another directory?

Tags: linux, bash, unix

In the same way that .bash_profile configures my shell before the initial command prompt, and similarly where .bashrc runs for every new terminal, can I have an equivalent when I move to another directory?

Ideally a bash function that sets env variables, sets aliases etc.. only when I enter a certain directory?

Comment: Look into the `$PROMPT_COMMAND` environment variable.

Comment: Technically, `.bashrc` is run for each new interactive shell, which is the most common command run by a new terminal window. `.bash_profile` is run for each new *login* shell, which in some environments (Mac OS X being the prominent example) happens with each new terminal window by default.

Answer (score 2):

You can make cd a function, and make it detect if you enter that particular directory.

```
cd () {
  builtin cd "$@"
  case $PWD in
    /some/directory) . ./profilefile;;
  esac
}
```

I don't recommend this approach, because it means the script will be executed even if you enter that directory for some reason that's unrelated to working on the project. I suggest having a specific function that changes to the project directory and sources the settings script.

```
myproj () {
  cd /some/directory && . ./profilefile
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For interactive sessions, pgl had the right idea. Here's an example using `PROMPT_COMMAND`:

```
$ cat foo
set_environment() {
  case "$PWD/" in
    /tmp/* )
      alias whatshere='echo "Only junk"'
      ;;
    /etc/* )
      alias whatshere='echo "Config files: " *'
      ;;
    * )
      unalias whatshere 2> /dev/null
  esac
}

PROMPT_COMMAND='set_environment'

$ source foo

$ cd ~
$ whatshere
bash: whatshere: command not found    

$ cd /tmp    
$ whatshere 
Only junk  

$ pushd /etc/apache2  # Also works when not using cd
/etc/apache2 /tmp
$ whatshere
Config files:  apache2.conf conf.d envvars magic  (...)
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know any Bash feature that do what you describe.
But you probably can trick by creating an alias (or a function) on cd

```
alias cd='echo Yooo ; cd'
```

or better (the alias is important to avoid an infinite loop...)

```
_cd() { if [ "$1" == 'toto' ]; then export TOTO=1; fi ; cd "$1"; }
alias cd="_cd"
```